# segfault from dmesg + redhat linux

Tags: rhel, kernel, dmesg

I see unusual info from the dmesg as the following:

```
addr2line[207071]: segfault at 30 ip 1000543d41881 sp 00037fff87dd4420 error 6
addr2line[207089]: segfault at 0 ip 0200353455f8c9052e sp 034347fffb8dd3980 error 6 in libbfd-2.20.51.0.2-5.36.el6.so[7f13f800+d2000]
addr2line[207100]: segfault at 0 ip 002075454f3652e sp 0503434ff084fd0a0 error 6 in libbfd-2.20.51.0.2-5.36.el6.so[7f836545440+d2000]
```

what this lines are indicate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Program `addr2line` had [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) with error 6 (attempt to write in unmapped memory). The program likely crashed at that point.

A detailed answer on how to interpret the message is provided on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2549363/8270535).